# Swift ZIPFoundation extract string in memory is not working

Tags: ios, swift, zipfoundation

I am using ZipFoundation in Swift from https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation

My requirement is unzip the file contents in memory and directly convert into String.

```
let archive = Archive(url: fileUrl, accessMode: .read, preferredEncoding: .utf8)
do{
   try archive?.extract(entry, consumer: {data in
      print(data.count)
    })
  }catch{}
```

The archive object is always null its not reading zip file. Also what is the entry object to pass to extract method?

Comment: Perhaps "entry" isn't in the zip file, what are you passing for "entry"?  What if you catch the error and print that?

Comment: Archive is nil (check fileUrl, permissions)?

Comment: the file is in assets folder so it have permission , also tried to access using NSData its reading. do you have any code to read in memory , could you please share ?

Comment: for entry in archive where entry.type == .file { print(entry.fileName); if let data = archive.extract(entry) { ... } }}

Comment: Don't you have a warning because you are doing a do/catch but no real try, since you are ignoring the possible thrown error with `try?`. At least, write `try!` instead and it might crash, or use `try` (with no question mark), and print the `error` caught in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZIP Foundation archives support subscripting. This allows you to obtain an `Entry` by subscripting into an `Archive` via `archive["path/to/file.txt"]`.

To get access to the contents of the obtained file, you use the closure-based version of `extract` as follows:

```
guard let archiveURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "archive", withExtension: "zip"),
      let archive = Archive(url: archiveURL, accessMode: .read),
      let entry = archive["test/data.random"]
else { return }

_ = try? archive.extract(entry) { data in
    print(data.count)
}
```